# Capture caller name before connecting call

Tags: twilio

I am looking for guidance/pointer on how to build a twilio webhook that will intercept calls to my twilio#, ask for caller name and then call me to check if I would like to be connected (announce caller name). If I answer yes, the call is connected otherwise it could go to my voicemail.
I see various features like Queue, Conference, Conditional Forward etc. but I am not sure which one will solve my need. Any pointers here?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have not. I am just confused as to which feature I should explore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Ok, to do this you need a few steps.

When the call comes in, you need to ask the caller their name. For this I would use [`<Gather>` with `input="speech"`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather?code-sample=code-gather-speech&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=5.x) to capture their name and a nested [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) to ask the question.

With `<Gather>` you need to provide an [`action` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#action) which is a URL that will get called when the user answers the question. When the URL is called, you get the result of the speech in the `SpeechResult` parameter in the body of the request.

Now you have the name you want to connect it to someone to answer. You could use [`<Enqueue>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/enqueue) for this, but we can work a bit more simple to start with. In the response to the request to your `action` URL you can return a [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial).

To get the message relayed to the person answering, we also need to use [`<Number>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number) within the `<Dial>`. [`<Number>` can use a `url` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-url) which will be requested when the person answer the phone. You can return more TwiML to this request and that TwiML will be played before the calls are connected. This is called a [whisper](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/call-whisper).

In this TwiML you can return another `<Gather>` with a nested `<Say>` that asks whether you want to take the call, using the gathered name. Finally, with the result of that you can then accept the call (by ending this line of TwiML) or [`<Hangup>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/hangup).

If you `<Hangup>` you'll want to move onto taking voicemail. You need to return to your TwiML that already has a `<Dial>` in it and add more TwiML after the `<Dial>`. Now you can use `<Say>` and then [`<Record>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record) to take the voicemail.

I hope that gives you an insight into what features to look into, and a map for how to put them together.

Comment: Thank you exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: will I be able to do this in Studio? I am trying to quickly POC this using Studio. But as I see, it doesn't seem to support whisper or connecting receiver to the call with prompt to answer/reject. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: No, it doesn't seem that there is any whisper functionality within Studio. This is a complex enough flow that you will need to program it for now.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, I actually managed to piece together something quick and is working great!